# EasyMock and Annotations and 2 dependencies of the same type

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, easymock

Recently, I've started using EasyMock 3.2 and its Annotation based testing feature which I liked a lot.
However I've faced a situation when I get an exception I don't know how to deal with.
I've modeled this situation and looking for advice how to test my class

1. Let's assume I have a class **Line** which contains two parameters a and b and can calculate the value of **y(x) = a * x + b**.
2. Let's assume I have an interface **Param** to denote a and b (for whatever reason, its just an example):

So my class looks like this:

```
public class Line {
    private Param paramA;
    private Param paramB;

    public int calculate(int x) {
       return paramA.intValue() * x + paramB.intValue();
    }

}
```

Interface Param is also dead simple:

```
public interface Param {
    int intValue();
}
```

Now I'm going to create a test for it. I use JUnit on java 7 and EasyMock 3.2 from IntelliJ.

```
import org.easymock.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;


@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class LineTest extends EasyMockSupport {

    @TestSubject
    private Line testSubject = new Line();

    @Mock(name = "paramA") //I've tried with and without 'name'
    private Param paramA;

    @Mock(name = "paramB")
    private Param paramB;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        expect(paramA.intValue()).andReturn(2);
        expect(paramB.intValue()).andReturn(4);
        replayAll();
        int actualResult = testSubject.calculate(3);
        // I expect to observe actualResult =  3 * 2 + 4  = 10
        assertEquals(10, actualResult);
        verifyAll();

    }
}
```

So far so good, however running the test produces the following Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: At least two mocks can be assigned to private 
Param Line.paramA: paramA and paramB
at org.easymock.EasyMockSupport.injectMocksOnClass(EasyMockSupport.java:665)
at org.easymock.EasyMockSupport.injectMocks(EasyMockSupport.java:640)
at org.easymock.EasyMockStatement.evaluate(EasyMockRunner.java:55)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

It looks like easymock can't inject mocks by field name but instead tried to mock by type and fails on ambiguity.

What is my mistake?

Thanks a lot in advance and have a nice day

Comment: I've not played with the annotation based mocking yet. But could you try this: Leaving the "name = Blah" bits in the annotations, could you try adding some setters to the Line class? So add setParamA and setParamB to the Line class to set the Param values. I wonder if EasyMock is struggling to set the values because there are no injectors, so it's trying to do them reflectively based on the type.

Comment: Having said the above, I'm not sure it will help either. I just found [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195820/how-should-i-use-easymocks-mock-annotation-new-in-version-3-2) that suggests that it is trying to do the injection reflectively based on the type. It looks like you might have to build your own mocks and set them yourself. Perhaps have a constructor that can take both the Param values and then use that in your test.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I've tried adding setters to Line class, it doesn't work neither. The exception is the same. I think easymock 3.2 just can't handle this situation. I guess, it's mock injection algorithm is vastly based on reflection and  it should be improved. I'll be more than happy to know that I'm wrong though :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the [docs](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#mocking-annotations) that specifically explain this part? You should be using the `fieldName` qualifier to disambiguate such assignments.

> The annotation has an optional element, `'type'`, to refine the mock
>   as a `'nice'` mock or a `'strict'` mock. Another optional annotation,
>   `'name'`, allows setting of a name for the mock that will be used in
>   the `createMock` call, which will appear in expectation failure
>   messages for example. **Finally, an optional element, `"fieldName"`,
>   allows specifying the target field name where the mock should be
>   injected. Mocks are injected to any field in any `@TestSubject` that
>   is of compatible type. If more than one mock can be assigned to the
>   same field then this is considered an error. The `fieldName` qualifier
>   can be used in this scenario to disambiguate the assignments.**

Emphasis mine.